# Links on site footer won't work after reducing screen width

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm struggling for days to find a solution for this problem. I'm doing the site below for a customer, the site is responsive and works well in multiple screen  sizes, but when i reduce the width to less than 765px, the links on the footer section (the gray background one) does not work ; they can't be clicked anymore, is like they become disabled when the width goes under 765px.

Could someone please inspect it on devtools and help me fix it ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the div with id 'sp-bottom4' needs a float left, maybe a width 100% as well to not have the elements below it float left with it.

Without the float left, the div seems to be over the links which disable it.